# Is there a tool to split Protractor tests into component files?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, automated-tests, protractor

I'm working on building an extensible automated test suite with Protractor (angularJS/Jasmine framework). 
As long as all of my variables and functions and jasmine are in the same file, it runs semi-okay. 
But every effort I make to break it into export/require is a nightmare.
Is there a tool that will just find the parts of my test and automatically reformat it and break it into individual files and folders, so that the thing will actually run?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don´t know a tool for what you want. However if I were you, I would keep working with node's way of sharing files (export/require). Once you understand it, if you keep it clean and tidy, you could grow your app in a "clean" way.

**EDIT:**

As @MBielski said, Page Objects Model is also helpful when maintaining you test code.

Definition from the Selenium team:

> Page Object is a Design Pattern which has become popular in test
>   automation for enhancing test maintenance and reducing code
>   duplication. A page object is an object-oriented class that serves as
>   an interface to a page of your AUT. The tests then use the methods of
>   this page object class whenever they need to interact with that page
>   of the UI. The benefit is that if the UI changes for the page, the
>   tests themselves don’t need to change, only the code within the page
>   object needs to change. Subsequently all changes to support that new
>   UI are located in one place.

And now an example without using page objects and then one using it.

**Without:**

```
describe('angularjs homepage', function() {
  it('should greet the named user', function() {
    browser.get('http://www.angularjs.org');
    element(by.model('yourName')).sendKeys('Julie');
    var greeting = element(by.binding('yourName'));
    expect(greeting.getText()).toEqual('Hello Julie!');
  });
});
```

**With:**

```
var AngularHomepage = function() {
  var nameInput = element(by.model('yourName'));
  var greeting = element(by.binding('yourName'));

  this.get = function() {
    browser.get('http://www.angularjs.org');
  };

  this.setName = function(name) {
    nameInput.sendKeys(name);
  };

  this.getGreeting = function() {
    return greeting.getText();
  };
};


describe('angularjs homepage', function() {
  it('should greet the named user', function() {
    var angularHomepage = new AngularHomepage();
    angularHomepage.get();

    angularHomepage.setName('Julie');

    expect(angularHomepage.getGreeting()).toEqual('Hello Julie!');
  });
});
```

You can also define various test suites. Take a look at this config file:

```
exports.config = {

  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },

  // Spec patterns are relative to the location of the spec file. They may
  // include glob patterns.
  suites: {
    homepage: 'tests/e2e/homepage/**/*Spec.js',
    search: ['tests/e2e/contact_search/**/*Spec.js',
      'tests/e2e/venue_search/**/*Spec.js']
  },

  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true, // Use colors in the command line report.
  }
};
```

Comment: Page objects should probably get a mention as well.